# Extending SLICK Tables in a DRY manner

Tags: scala, slick

I have an interesting question around Slick/Scala that I am hoping that one of you nice chaps might be able to assist me with.

I have several tables and by extension in SLICK case classes

```
case class A(...)
case class B(...)
case class C(...)
```

that share these common fields

```
(id: String, livemode: Boolean, created: DateTime, createdBy : Option[Account]) .
```

Because these fields are repeated in every case class, I'd like to explore the possibility of extracting them into a single object or type.

However, when creating the SLICK table objects I would like things to end up where these common fields are included too so I can persist their individual values in each table.

```
object AsTable extends Table[A]("a_table") { 
  ...
  def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def livemode = column[Boolean]("livemode", O.NotNull)
  def created = column[DateTime]("created", O.NotNull)
  def createdBy = column[Account]("created_by", O.NotNull)
  ... 
}
```

Effectively, the end result I'm looking for is to allow me make changes to the common fields without having to update each table.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have not tried this, but how about a trait you mix in:

```
trait CommonFields { this: Table[_] =>
  def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def livemode = column[Boolean]("livemode", O.NotNull)
  def created = column[DateTime]("created", O.NotNull)
  def createdBy = column[Account]("created_by", O.NotNull)

  protected common_* = id ~ livemode ~ created ~ createdBy 
}
```

Then you can do:

```
object AsTable extends Table[(String,Boolean,DateTime,Account,String)]("a_table") 
    with CommonFields { 
  def foo = column[String]("foo", O.NotNull)
  def * = common_* ~ foo
}
```

The only thing you'll have to repeat now is the type of the elements.

**UPDATE**

If you want to do object-mapping and:

1. You map to case-classes
2. The fields in your case classes are in the same order

Just do:

```
case class A(
    id: String,
    livemode: Boolean,
    created: DateTime,
    createdBy: Account,
    foo: String)

object AsTable extends Table[A]("a_table") with CommonFields { 
  def foo = column[String]("foo", O.NotNull)
  def * = common_* ~ foo <> (A.apply _, A.unapply _)
}
```

This seems to be the most economical solution (rather then trying to define `*` in `CommonFields` and adding a type parameter). However, it requires you to change all case classes if your fields change.

We could try to mitigate this by using composition on the case classes:

```
case class Common(
    id: String,
    livemode: Boolean,
    created: DateTime,
    createdBy: Account)

case class A(
    common: Common,
    foo: String)
```

However, when constructing the mapper function, we will (somewhere) end up having to convert tuples of the form:

```
(CT_1, CT_2, ... CT_N, ST_1, ST_2, ..., ST_M)
```

`CT` Common type (known in `CommonFields`)
`ST` Specific type (known in `AsTable`)

To:

```
(CT_1, CT_2, ... CT_N), (ST_1, ST_2, ..., ST_M)
```

In order to pass them to subroutines individually converting `Common` and `A` to and from their tuples.

We have to do this without knowing the number or the exact types of either `CT` (when implementing in `AsTable`) or `ST` (when implementing in `CommonFields`). *The tuples in the Scala standard library are unable to do that*. You would need to use `HLists` as for exampled offered by [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) to do this.

It is questionable whether this is worth the effort.

The basic outline could look like this (without all the implicit mess which will be required). This code will not compile like this.

```
trait CommonFields { this: Table[_] =>
  // like before

  type ElList = String :: Boolean :: DateTime :: Account :: HNil

  protected def toCommon(els: ElList) = Common.apply.tupled(els.tupled)
  protected def fromCommon(c: Common) = HList(Common.unapply(c))
}

object AsTable extends Table[A] with CommonFields {
  def foo = column[String]("foo", O.NotNull)

  def * = common_* ~ foo <> (x => toA(HList(x)), x => fromA(x) tupled)

  // convert HList to A
  protected def toA[L <: HList](els: L) = {
    // Values for Common
    val c_els = els.take[Length[ElList]]
    // Values for A
    val a_els = toCommon(c_els) :: els.drop[Length[ElList]]

    A.apply.tupled(a_els.tupled)
  }

  // convert A to HList
  protected def fromA(a: A) =
    fromCommon(a.common) :: HList(A.unapply(a)).drop[One]

}
```

Using some more type magic you can probably resolve the last two issues:

1. Put `toA` and `fromA` into the base trait (by using type parameters in the trait, or using abstract type members)
2. Avoid defining `ElList` explicitly by extracting it from `Common.apply` by using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068464/is-there-a-generic-way-to-invert-the-order-of-the-arguments-of-a-curried-functio/17072544#17072544)

Comment: Thanks. I did think about this approach earlier. But how would you handle the table definition.

    Table[(String,Boolean,DateTime,Account,String)]

Is there any way to avoid having to touch there too when changing the common fields? What if I object mapping as a requirement as well?

Comment: Almost there. I can confirm that this pattern works to an extent. So what about the case classes? Assuming my case class is defined as....

   A(foo: Int, B: String, C: String)

In order to use object mapping the common fields must be present in its definition. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @RasputinJones please see updated answer. Answering your last comment: You need the common fields somewhere in the object to fill them out in the table again.

Comment: >> It is questionable whether this is worth the effort. 
Yup. I have to agree. Thanks for how far you got. 

I'd like to read the pointers though so pls send over.

Kudos!

Comment: @RasputinJones There you go. Welcome to Scala's Turing-complete type system :P

Comment: Is there a way to get Codegen to automatically mix in a trait such as CommonFields?

Comment: what imports do you have for CommonFields (Slick 3.1.1 nowadays) so it would be driver agnostic. I can't seem a way to make this work with newer versions of slick

Comment: @Sorona for Slick 3 you should import jdbc API (e.g., slick.jdbc.H2Profile.api._), and use braces instead tilde for `def *` (see [Slick 3 p.34](http://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.pdf)) .