# Common Case Class Variables

Tags: scala, case-class

Does anyone have any thoughts/better way to handle common fields that cross multiple case classes...for example I have the following case class;

```
case class Customer(
    name: String,
    refId: String = ReferenceIdGenerator.generateRefId("CUSTOMER"),
    createdAt: DateTime = DateTime.now,
    updatedAt: DateTime = DateTime.now,
    id: Option[Long] = None)
```

The last four variables are repeated in every "model/domain" case class in my example application.  Is there a better way to remove that common boilerplate code?

One thought would be to create a "common" case class and at least the boilerplate code is limited, for example;

```
case class CommonFields(refId: String...etc)
case class Customer(name: String, common: CommonFields)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

> One thought would be to create a "common" case class and at least the boilerplate code is limited, for example

Yes, this is the correct solution, assuming this works well with whatever you use to interact with the database. If you are using Slick, see also [Extending SLICK Tables in a DRY manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244510/extending-slick-tables-in-a-dry-manner).

Comment: if it is common then you can probably name it with something that makes sense in your domain, "CommonFields" does not mean anything, but maybe AuditData(created: DateTime, updated: DateTime) does.

Comment: I second this approach, which I've used in the past. It would be nice if there were an easy way to do this with DRYness, like have a base constructor you could concatenate against subclass constructors to still present a flat interface to client code. This may be possible in shapeless or using macros; I've never done it though.